# Application restarting after going to home screen

Tags: codenameone

I have an android app designed using [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

1)I run my application

2)I click on the home button of the phone.My app is taken away from my app and home screen is shown to me.

3)I again click on my application after navigating to it from the menu.

I expect that the state of my application be restored. But what happens is, my application restarts.

Also, this behaviour is arbitrary. Sometimes the application restarts and at other times the application resumes its state. Most of the times it restarts.

How do i ensure that my application always resumes its old state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android restarts running applications on some conditions to preserve RAM, battery etc. If you use the task switcher the application will resume properly but relaunching it often restarts it.

We are working on improving this behavior in the next update to Codename One, but you can use the stop method to store the application state into storage and use the start method to restore the application state.

Comment: How do i do that? Umm, do i get an event on the press of home button? I am not sure how to go about this. What should i be looking at?

Comment: Just store the state from the state machine in storage rather than in variables. When start() is invoked just restore the last existing state.

Comment: How would this behave if the user decides to kill the application. The application will always launch from the last state preserved, while the user will expect it to launch from the start

Comment: True, that would be a problem. You can detect such a situation by detecting init/start where stop/destroy were never invoked.